# How to get real file name without tilde substitution

Tags: c++, tilde

I use dirent.h library for fetching name of file. While most of them are correct, this one:

1ZdjĂ„â„˘cie gÄąâ€šÄ‚Ĺ‚wne.JPG_38ba97e477158efb3563274f5bd39af7.jpg_cda6829b61253f64b44a5c7f15e00b45 - Copy.jpg

is read as

1ZDJCI~2.JPG

What can I do to prevent tilde substition behavior?

I use Windows 7, Visual Studio C++

path    "./tiles/"

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir(path.c_str())) != NULL) {
while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
if( strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0 ) { continue; }
string a(ent->d_name);
```

examples of "correct" (without tilde substitution) file names:
"2012-07-29-
227.jpg_955c70788013c4979d5cad857b49d4d2.jpg_8551b27380326b183c17e3469ec97cd3.jpg"
"2012-07-29-228.jpg_5b2281bbe1efd6bd7469c4a29114a210.jpg_ee6d3a75864e7e33b3d99c023c962dbf.jpg"
"2012-08-31-842.jpg_93562fa908083e5a070467558bba2141.jpg_2e84cdbc1d5a5eb932a1373840119aa4.jpg"

Comment: ... have sane filenames?

Comment: How are you getting the file name?

Comment: 'dirent.h` - it's a POSIX compat interface

Comment: List a few filenames that are "correct".

Comment: The method you are using probably doesn't support Unicode and/or long paths. Maybe use UTF-16 Win32 functions and convert back to UTF-8 or whatever encoding you want to use? Unless you need something cross-platform.

Comment: I added code and examples of 'correct' file names i think it is POSIX interface. I haven't test windows functions for reading directory content so probably its good clue - use posix library on linux and windows on windows but maybe there is a cross-platform solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the short name (NAME~1.EXT) to it's long name.